# Evaluating goodness-of-fit in sequential multiregression

Tags: multiple-regression, goodness-of-fit

I am doing a sequential multiregression analysis where I look at how four independent variables (porosity, permeability, sandstone thickness and sandstone depth) labeled $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4$ influence the oil flow rate (labeled $y$) in a reservoir.  I have calculated the regression coefficients as well as the goodness-of-fit value for each step in the sequence.  My method has been the use of the matrix equation based on least-squares criterion for the computation of regression coefficients.  For my goodness-of-fit caluclation I have used the formula:

$$R^2 = \gamma_{m}^2 \cdot 100 \%$$

where

$$\gamma_{m}^2 = \frac{\sum^{n}(\hat{y_i} - \bar{y})^2}{\sum^{n}(y_{i} - \bar{y})^2}$$

So basically my work flow is as follows:

Step 1: $y = f(x_1) \rightarrow R_{1}^2$

Step 2: $y = f(x_1, x_2) \rightarrow R_{2}^2$

Step 3: $y = f(x_1,x_2,x_3) \rightarrow R_{3}^2$

Step 4: $y = f(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4) \rightarrow R_{4}^2$

Where each $R^2$ represents the regression line's goodness-of-fit.

When I run through this sequence I find that the goodness-of-fit values change as follows for each step (values in %):

Step 1: $R_{1}^2 = 6.0677$

Step 2: $R_{2}^2 = 14.7614$

Step 3: $R_{3}^2 = 15.5811$

Step 4: $R_{4}^2 = 96.2177$

So from this my conclusion would be that variable 3 (thickness) has very poor influence on the flow rate as there is only a slight increase in $R^2$ between steps 2 and 3. In other words, $x_3$ only influences $y$ with $0.82 \%$.

However, if I alternate the order in which I perform my sequential calculation I get a different interpretation of the data.  Say that instead of calculating the sequence in the order $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$ I do this in the order $x_3,x_1,x_2,x_4$.  I then get the following values for goodness-of-fit for each progressive step:

Step 1: $R_{1}^2 = 9.9240$

Step 2: $R_{2}^2 = 10.0542$

Step 3: $R_{3}^2 = 15.5811$

Step 4: $R_{4}^2 = 96.2177$

So from this analysis it would seem that it is the varilable added in step 2 (variable 1 - the porosity), which has the lowest influence on the overall goodness-of-fit.  And here variable 3 (thickness) appears to have a bigger influence with a value of $9.9240$.

I am quite green when it comes to statistics so I'm not sure exactly how to interpret this.  If there is not an error in my program (I don't think it is but I can supply the MATLAB code I've created if you wish), how does this make sense intuitively?  How can we really infer what variables influence or do not influence our dependent variable $y$ and the overall goodness-of-fit, when the order in which we perform or sequential multiregression will influence our results?  I see that the end result becomes the same i both cases, but I am interested in finding out more clearly which variables are relevant and which are not.

Any help/insight/explanations will be greatly apprecaited!

Comment: Welcome to our site! The really useful answers to this question have to be extensive and complicated, because there are many issues lurking related to statistical significance, confounding, causality, overfitting, and more. Fortunately you can find good answers already on this site within the threads [tagged with "model-selection" and "regression"](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=[model-selection]%20regression), to which I refer you for further information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are facing multicollinearity problem. So check the correlation matrix of your varaibles. With highly correlated variables your interpretation is never unambiguous.

If you still need the most-significant variable, you should rather start with a 4-variable fit. Then make 4 other fits *excluding* each variable (one variable in each fit). Observe how much the R2 drops. When it drops at most, the variable excluded is the most significant. The second-largest drop is for the next-significant variable and so on.

Another technique is not to exclude, but randomly *permute*  a single variable across your data points. Again, permuting the most significant one would cause the largest drop in the score.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions!  I will definitely try this out!